# Does the current E2652 EpiServer Developer Masterclass certification exam only ask questions about EPiServer CMS 6 R2?

Tags: episerver

I have had look around online for preparation materials for the E2652 EpiServer Developer Masterclass certification exam. I genuinely do not have much to go on at present. I found this old link but much of might not apply to E2652 EpiServer Developer Masterclass certification exam: [Episerver 5 exam tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556221/does-anyone-have-any-episerver-exam-tips). However, EPiServer has moved on since CMS 5: there are a few changes since CMS 5, such as MVC and Dynamic Data Store. Importantly, I do not even know of which version(s) of EPiServer CMS it demands knowledge - Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good link to a blog post that Rouslan Minasian wrote about the episerver exam.

[Rouslans Blog Post](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Rouslan-Minasian/Dates/2010/8/EPiServer-Certification/)

Answer (score 0):

Another blog post (concerning the CMS 6 test): http://fringan.blogspot.se/2012/03/reflections-from-taking-episerver-cms-6.html